# Springboot How to Return a response after a POST

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, response

I would like to create a new customer and return a customer number once the customer is created. The customer number has to be an auto incremented unique number from 50000.

Thus far i have managed to created a customer but i am not sure how i should go about generating the customer number, save it to the database and show it to the user as a success message when a POST is triggered.

Below json is the desired response;

```
{
    "customerNumber": "50002",
    "statusMessage": "Customer Created Successfully",
}
```

And the following snippet from controller and service;

**UserService.java**

```
public void createUser(User user) {
    if (user == null || user.getId() == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
    } else {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**RegistrationController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users")
public void createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.createUser(user);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Annotate the class containing `createUser` with `@RestController`, or add `@ResponseBody` on `createUser` method directly, and change its return type to `Response`;

```
@RestController
class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users")
    public Response createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

Assuming your `createUser` method in `UserService` will return a `Response`;

```
public Response createUser(User user) {
    if (user == null || user.getId() == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
    } else {
        User user = userRepository.save(user);
        return new Response(user.getId);
    }
}
```

Since `fooRepository.save()` always returns the successfully saved entity as long as it is the native `save` method from `CrudRepository`.

The `id` field will be present inside the resulting `User` entity from `save`, to return the type of response you want, you'd need to create such a class, and transfer the aforementioned `id`;

```
class Response {

    private String customerNumber;
    private String statusMessage;

    public Response(String id) {
        this.customerNumber = id;
        this.statusMessage = "Customer Created Successfully";
    }

    // getters, setters, etc
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For your controller to be able to return the id, the service layer should be able to provide that information.

In other words, a service or the repository should be able to inform you the id of the last added user. After getting that information, you can use it in the controller.

For example, some repository implementations set the id of the entity with the generated id after the saving (and commit of the transaction). If that was your case, you could do:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/users")
@ResponseBody
public long createUser(@RequestBody User user){
     userService.createUser(user);
     return user.getId();
}
```

Notice the addition of the `return` clause, the returning type and the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: how does @ResponseBody help, the return type is the same. I was expecting it would return it as a JSON

Comment: @garg10may Maybe you are confusing things. For instance, `1` ***is*** a valid JSON. It's just a number, maybe that's why you think it isn't JSON. (In that case, check the header just to make sure the `content-type` is `application/json` or similar)

Comment: yes sorry :') I was thinking something like `{ path: 1, message: success}` like spring-boot already provides